# "vector<T> too long" error while filling std::vector

Tags: c++, vector

i am trying to fill a two dimensional vector(817 by 577) with objects called cells. These cells have a set of member values (floats, other vectors etc). At a certain point the program stops and throws the error `"vector<T> too long"`.
Here is the class definition of cells and the complete loop:

```
struct cell
    {
    int x;
    int y;
    int country;
    vector<int> popO;
    vector<int> popS;
    vector<float> Rainfall;
    double Cropland;
    vector<movement> outm;
    vector<movement> inm;
    vector<double> AgeMaleFemale;
    vector<double> AgeMaleFemaleMortality;
    double Fertility;
    };
vector<vector<cell>> cells;
void fillCells(dataserver D)
        {
        cout<<"start filling"<<endl;
        int rows=577;
        int columns=817;
        cell X;
        vector<vector<cell>> output(rows,vector<cell>(columns,X));
        cout<<"start loop"<<endl;
        for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
            {
            cout<<i<<" ";
            for (int j=0;j<columns;j++)
                {
                int p=-9999;
                cell tmpC;
                tmpC.x=i;
                tmpC.y=j;
                tmpC.country=D.CO[i][j];
                tmpC.popO.resize(3,0);
                tmpC.popO[0]=int(D.PO[0][i][j]);
                tmpC.popO[1]=int(D.PO[1][i][j]);
                tmpC.popO[2]=int(D.PO[2][i][j]);
                tmpC.Rainfall.resize(10,0);
                for (int k=0;k<10;k++)
                    {
                    tmpC.Rainfall[k]=D.R[k][i][j];
                    }
                tmpC.popS.resize(10,0);
                tmpC.Cropland=D.CPC[i][i];
                if (tmpC.country!=-9999)
                    {
                    tmpC.Fertility=D.F[tmpC.country];
                    tmpC.AgeMaleFemale.resize(18,0);
                    tmpC.AgeMaleFemale=D.AMF[tmpC.country];
                    tmpC.AgeMaleFemaleMortality.resize(18,0);
                    tmpC.AgeMaleFemaleMortality=D.M[tmpC.country];
                    }
                output[i][j]=tmpC;
                }
            }
        cells=output;
        }
```

Googling a bit I found out that sizeof(cell) times the number of cells in the vector is supposed to smaller than vector::max_size()

sizeof(cell) is 144 ->144*817*577=67882896

max_size is 268345455

Shouldn't there be enough space for all the cells then, or am I missing something?
Thanks in advance!

Some additional Info:

Running on Windows 7 64bit, compiling with Visual Studio 2010, 32 bit

The info about max_size actually came from here:
[stl "vector<T> too long"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955400/stl-vectort-too-long)

Comment: Why not print the vector's length once in a while to _verify_ your assumption of its length?

Comment: *Googling a bit I found out that sizeof(cell) times the number of cells in the vector is supposed to smaller than vector::max_size()* I don't quite know where you got that from, but it is not *correct* (something similar might be true, but I think you misinterpreted whatever you read)

Comment: Please, take the time to copy the exact error message you are getting with as much context information (on the error) as possible

Comment: `max_size - This value is typically equal to std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max(), and reflects the theoretical limit on the size of the container. At runtime, the size of the container may be limited to a value smaller than max_size() by the amount of RAM available.`

Comment: Which system are you using? Windows? Which compiler? std::vector<T> is a data-structure with an array like semantic and the ability to dynamically increase its size at runtime. Since you don't seem to need the latter feature maybe you should just use a common 2D array?

Comment: @DumbCoder - don't know where that quote came from, but it's wrong. `max_size()` is the maximum **`size`**, that is, the largest number of elements; it's typically `std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() / sizeof(element)`.

Comment: You have no vector here larger than 817 elements (specifically 577 of those). I'm fairly confident those numbers are significantly lower than any theoretical limits on a vector's indexable reach. Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @PeteBecker http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/max_size

Comment: Pete Becker vs whoever wrote that line on cppreference.com in battle of "general statements about what most C++ implementations do" ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop - C++11 says that `max_size()` returns "`distance(begin(), end())` for the largest possible container. So, sure, it's possible that that statement reflects non-conforming implementations, but that's not useful information. Not that `max_size()` itself is useful, of course.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I think the ambiguity is in the word "possible" -- presumably if an implementation happens to know that its own memory allocator has an overhead of a few bytes, it's not required to report `max_size` as `(std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() - a_few) / sizeof(T)` for containers using `std::allocator<T>`.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, thats what I thought, but where else could the problem be? I mean it definitely occurs within this loop

Comment: @SteveJessop - granted, the requirement is essentially meaningless, so pretty much any large number is valid, but good engineering still demands doing as good a job as possible, not just throwing out a value that will never be wrong. It's not the allocator, but the size of the address space and the size of the element that determines the maximum container size.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit isnt the vector length defined with rows and columns? I mean the size is not changing, only the sizes of small vectors within a cell

Comment: @PeteBecker: I guess there are trickier cases than `vector` anyway. For example the implementer knows for sure that a `std::list<char>` requires more than one byte per element, so presumably should divide by the size of whatever node structure is used internally.

Comment: @SteveJessop - yup, `std::list<char>` is a better example.

Comment: So another (unrelated) question, was it your intention to pass your data server by-value ? (that seems to be a theme in this code, as there is a *ton* of copying going on, but I was just curious).

Comment: @WhozCraig no, not intentional, should I pass a pointer instead? (If so, could you briefly explain why?)

Comment: @user2160180 - sorry for the digression about `max_size()`. To find out what's going wrong, start commenting out code until the problem goes away. So, for example, don't store anything into `tmpC`; just stuff the default-initialized cell into `output`. If that works, start adding back bits and pieces of the data until you've identified the culprit.

Comment: @user2160180: My point is that you have a problem that you don't understand, so to debug it you need to _verify_ your assumptions. You'll find that at least one of them doesn't hold, else you wouldn't be here!

Comment: @user2160180 regarding all the copying, you can probably substantially reduce it. [possible example](http://pastebin.com/Me3d6mEW)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since I havent got enough rep to comment, so you get it as an answer.

The error text sounds like you are on a windows machine
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2af6btx2%28v=vs.80%29.ASPX

And I think it has to do with a resize, since creating a vector that is too big throws bad_alloc (on linux, so it might be different on windows).

Try and wrap all resize calls in a

```
try {
    // resize call here
} catch (Exception &e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl
              << "Some text that identifies the line" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This is why rep barriers don't work. People assume the rep barriers are there to force them to break the system, rather than say "oh ok, I'll shut up for now then". Annoyingly, this is a poor example because your "comment" is insightful and useful. Thanks for posting it! I mean, really, this _is_ an answer...

Comment: While this did not provide the answer, wrapping different block in try statements to see exactly which call causes the exception did help. Its  "tmpC.Fertility=D.F[tmpC.country];" It seems to bee an index out of bounds problem, since the country index begins with 1, the vector with 0. So thanks a lot!